# Rails: rollback from after_create without throwing Exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm developing a plugin for Redmine (RoR 4.2) that should send data to a different system once an Issue of a certain type is created/updated.

I've created a patch for Issue containing two callbacks: `before_update` and `after_create`. Both call the same method to execute. The reason why I use `after_create` is that I need to send the ID of a newly created Issue to the second system.

My problem here is that while returning `false` from `before_update` cancels the transaction, doing so from `after_create` has no effect. To handle this I need to throw an Exception which in its turn breaks the Issue controller making it return `Error 500` page instead of a nice error popup.

So what is the best way to handle this situation taking into account that I'm not willing to override the controller (if possible)?

Comment: Why not use a single `after_save` callback? I think it makes more sense to send a notification **after**  the update has been done (successfully), because if done before you may send false data if the update fails.

Comment: @MrYoshiji, this makes sense, and once I find a neat way to handle Exceptions required to rollback from `after_save`, I'll switch to it.

Comment: If you switch to it now, it should eliminate the exception.

Comment: @MrYoshiji, No, it won't because I'm the one throwing this exception. I need it to rollback the transaction in case API call fails because ActiveRecord ignores values returned from `after_save`

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a fool's errand since exceptions are generally handled on the controller layer. Of course you can rescue the exception in your callback method and for example log a message.

But you can't really effect the controllers outcome from a model callback without resorting to some really nasty hacks. The model should only be concerned with its own state - not the application flow.

And ActiveRecord does not really care about the return value from `after_*` callbacks.

Fat models and skinny controllers are good. But letting your models do stuff like talk across the wire or send emails is usually a horrible idea. ActiveRecord models are already doing a million things too many just maintaining your data and business logic. They should not be concerned with stuff like what happens when your request to API x fails.

You might want to consider using a [Service Object](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services) to wrap creating and updating the model instead.

Comment: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/the-only-acceptable-use-for-callbacks-in-rails-ever/

Comment: I'm guessing in the case of Redmine there should be some sort of hook or callback in the controller action that you can latch onto. But I don't have any experience developing for it.

Comment: Using Service Objects looks like a good idea, but as far as I get it, I have to override create/update methods in the controller to include calls to these services. As I'm talking about a plugin this may very well lead to conflicts should any other plugin decide to override the same methods.

Comment: As for hooks, Redmine controllers do have some, but they don't seem to affect app workflow - i.e. can't prevent Issue from being saved by returning something from such a hook.

Comment: You may be able to use the `before_commit` callback. It's not very documented but was added back in feb. https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18936

Comment: Leaving out all the details, if the API returns OK, we should save the Issue as it normally happens. If the API returns FAIL we should prevent the Issue from being saved and show an error message to the user. Thanks, I'll look into `before_commit`